# Signals wise, how does dropping an ingress packet due to policing look like?

Tags: qos

The context of my question is actually another question which is "Why isn't ingress shaping possible?". So yes, I get the whole "you can't affect packets you haven't received yet" idea, but we can't drop a packet before we get it either, yet we are able to do so with policing.

Thanks.

Comment: Are we talking about shaping on the same box that initially receives it? I could see some uncertainty coming in if we are shaping at a simpler edge device, but interested in traffic passing through a core device.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I get the whole ...

Apparently not. Your router cannot do anything with or about a packet until it has crossed the wire and arrived at the router. At *that* point, it can drop it. However, at that point, bandwidth has already been used. "Policing" doesn't change that.

Comment: So what's the point of policing on the inbound interface if it doesn't affect the bandwidth?

Comment: You guys seem to be debating absurd points.  Policing works because packets are selectively dropped based on the arrival rate of prior traffic in a defined time window.  The bandwidth consumed by one individual packet is largely irrelevant except to the degree it affects the calculated average input rate

Comment: "ingress shaping" generally isn't possible because you cannot stop the sender (ISP router) from sending you packets. They can be dropped after they've crosses the link to you, but they've used bandwidth at that point.

Comment: Would this not make a difference in a situation where accepted traffic hits the CPU, while shaped traffic gets dropped before the CPU? I'm just thinking something with multiple VPN tunnels but insufficient CPU for them all... or maybe some kind of fun security filtering via CPU...